# Mongo filed name change not updating indexes

Tags: mongodb, indexing, rename

While I undertand a foreign key constraint would not make sense for a NoSql database, should it not ensure that it updates the indexes if it allows me to rename fields?
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24rename

```
{ $rename : { old_field_name : new_field_name } }
```

but if I had

```
db.mycollections.ensureIndex({old_field_name:1});
```

wouldn't it be great if the index was updated automatically?

Is it that since system.indexes is simply just another table and such a automatic update would imply a foreign key constraint of sorts, the index update is not done? Or am I missing certain flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting Mike O' Brien:

The $rename operator is analogous to doing a $set/$unset in a single atomic operation. It's a shortcut for situations where you need to take a value and move it into another field, without the need to do it in 2 steps (one to fetch the value of the field, another to set the new one).

Doing a $rename does mean the data is changing. If I use $rename to rename a field named "x" to "y", but the field named "y" already existed in the document, the old value for "y" is overwritten, and the field "x" will no longer exist anymore. If either "x" or "y" is indexed, then the operation will update those indexes to reflect the final values resulting from the operation. The same applies when using rename to move a field from within an embedded document up to the top level (e.g. renaming "a.b" to "c") or vice versa.

The behavior suggested in the SO question (i.e., renaming a field maintains the relationship between the field it was moved to and its value in the index) then things can get really confusing and make it difficult to reason about what the "correct" expected behavior is for certain operations. For example, if I create an index on field "A" in a collection, rename "A" to "B" in one of the documents, and then do things like:
update({"A" : }, {"$set":{"B":}})   // find a document where A= and set its value of B to 
update({"B" : }, {"$set":{"A":}})   // find a document where B= and set its value of A to

Should these be equivalent?
In general, having the database maintain indexes across a collection by field name is a design decision that keeps behavior predictable and simple.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't do it.

The answer to your question *"wouldn't it be great if the index was updated automatically?"* is, *"no, not really"*.

If you think that renaming fields is a good idea you can add the new index yourself at the same time.  You'll likely have lots of other changes to do in your code to reflect a rename on a field (queries, updates, map reduce operations, ...) so why do you think it should single out index recreation as something that should happen automatically on what is a very rare operation when it's just one thing out of *many* that you'd need to do, manually?

If you care about this feature, go request it, 10Gen are incredibly responsive to suggestions, but I wouldn't be surprised if the answer was *"why is this important?"*

Comment: it's worth pointing out that a re-index is quite an intensive operation relatively speaking too - it could be dangerous to allow a rename to kick off a reindex by default, so if anything it might be something that would be added as an option.  Knowing how the devs work in 10gen I can say that there is an effort to minimise the knobs and options and be smart about default behavior rather than just add lots and lots of potentially confusing options.  All that being said, if it's something you would like file a request in Jira and see what response you get.

Comment: There should be no rename field operation available in that case. It would be easier for the db to tell me that there are indexes on the field being renamed and warn.

Comment: Personally I think they made a good choice.  Your opinion about what they "should" do would be best addressed by filing a suggestion with 10Gen as this is a Q&A forum not a place for subjective debate.